# cache search result implementation

Tags: java, mysql, caching

Database: mysql -- the table structure is.

```
------------------------------------------
phone_no (This is PK)    | month   | year
------------------------------------------
varchar(15)              | INT (2) | INT(4)
```

This has milions of records, now when a user access the site for the first time in a month, then i have to make a entry in the DB, otherise nothing will happen, This is for reporting purpose. my Java code is:

```
The VO ---->
         public class UesrAccessInfo {
            private String phone_no;
            private int year;
            private int month;
             .. getters and setters ...
        }
```

Now the java code to access the table is :

/* following methods are implemented in java code, no db accesses are there */

```
String phone_no = getPhoneNumber(); 
int currentMonth = getCurMonth(); 
int currentYear = getCurYear(; 

if (phone_no == null ) {
     request.setAttribute("firstAccessInCurrentMonth", false);
} 
else{
    UesrAccessInfo oUesrAccessInfo = new UesrAccessInfo();
    oUesrAccessInfo.setPhone_no(phone_no);
    UserAcessHistoryDBUtil.getUesrAccessInfo(oUesrAccessInfo);

    //////////// Code  for getUesrAccessInfo() in UserAcessHistoryDBUtil class /////////////
      String sql = "select month , year from user_access_history where phone_no= ?";
      String[][] rs = new MyDBAccessor().getPreparedTable(sql,new String[] { oUesrAccessInfo.getMsisdn() });
      if (rs != null && rs.length > 0) {
         for (String[] item : rs) {
            oUesrAccessInfo.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(item[0]));
            oUesrAccessInfo.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(item[1]));
         }
      }else{
        oUesrAccessInfo.setMonth(0);
      }
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * User is already present in database
     */
    if(oUesrAccessInfo.getMonth() != 0){

        /**
         * User has already accessed the site in current month
         */
        if(oUesrAccessInfo.getYear() == currentYear && oUesrAccessInfo.getMonth() == currentMonth){
            request.setAttribute("firstAccessInCurrentMonth", false);
        }
        else{
            UserAcessHistoryDBUtil.updateUserAccessHistory(phone_no, ""+ currentMonth, "" + currentYear);
            request.setAttribute("firstAccessInCurrentMonth", true);
        }
    }
    /**
     * User is not present in database
     */
    else{
        UserAcessHistoryDBUtil.createUserAccessHistory(phone_no,""+ currentMonth, "" + currentYear);
        request.setAttribute("firstAccessInCurrentMonth", true);
    }
}
```

SO, here i am facing the performance issue. I cant use caching, as there can be out of memory error in server.

Any suggestion , to improve the performance, i am new in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions

- Since this is done just for reporting purpose and is not going to
  affect the user, why don't you [run it in a separate thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)?
- You could do an insert for each access into some TableA and create a batch process which would do a bulk insert into the table you are currently inserting into. At least that would avoid running the select query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but finally i am implementating ehcache for this :)

Comment: Sorry for that, actually that time my concern is the cache will use jvm memory and thus can crash, but i found that by ehcache i can also use external memory. Sorry for my unknowing about the caching. The final implementation will be data will be fetched, updated and inserted in cache and when a certain limit crossed, a backend job will update the database. :)